# How to fix IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1 in android

Tags: android, list, arraylist, android-adapter

In my application I want to get some list data from server and set this into **Adapter** for show items.
I write below codes, but when run, the application shows me a **Force Close** error and show this error in `Logcat`.

**Error Message :**

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
at app.test.Adapters.CelebrityDetailAdapter.AwardGoldenAdapter.onBindViewHolder(AwardGoldenAdapter.java:53)
at app.test.Adapters.CelebrityDetailAdapter.AwardGoldenAdapter.onBindViewHolder(AwardGoldenAdapter.java:23)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6356)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6389)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5335)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5598)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5440)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5436)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2224)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1551)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1511)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:595)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3583)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3312)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3844)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19393)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6022)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1080)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19393)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6022)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1080)
```

**Adapter code:**

```
public class AwardGoldenAdapter extends    RecyclerView.Adapter<AwardGoldenAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<Award> model;
private int modelImage;
private int won, nominated, total;

public AwardGoldenAdapter(Context context, List<Award> model, int won, int nominated) {
    this.context = context;
    this.model = model;
    this.won = won;
    this.nominated = nominated;

    if (won > 0) {
        total = won;
    } else {
        total = nominated;
    }
}

@Override
public AwardGoldenAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_award, parent, false);

    return new AwardGoldenAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final AwardGoldenAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    if (model.get(position).getWon()) {
        modelImage = R.drawable.golden_globe_gold;
    } else {
        modelImage = R.drawable.golden_globe_silver;
    }
    Glide.with(context)
            .load(modelImage)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.default_image)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
            .into(holder.row_awardImg);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return total;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private ImageView row_awardImg;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        row_awardImg = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_awardImg);

    }
}
}
```

**My codes in activity for get data from server** (for server connection I use `Retrofit`) :

```
    private void getGoldenGlobeData() {
    celebrityAwardSendData = new CelebrityAwardSendData();
    celebrityAwardSendData.setCelebrityID(celebrityID);

    InterfaceApi api = ApiClient.getClient().create(InterfaceApi.class);
    Call<CelebrityAwardResponse> call = api.getCelebrityAward(celebrityAwardSendData);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<CelebrityAwardResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<CelebrityAwardResponse> call, Response<CelebrityAwardResponse> response) {
            if (response.body().getData() != null) {
                awardModel.clear();
                List<Award> won = new ArrayList<>();
                List<Award> lost = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Award award : response.body().getData().get(1).getAwards()) {
                    if (!award.getWon()) {
                        lost.add(award);
                    } else {
                        won.add(award);
                    }
                }
                if (won.size() > 0) {
                    awardModel.addAll(won);
                } else {
                    awardModel.addAll(lost);
                }

                awardGoldenAdapter = new AwardGoldenAdapter(context, awardModel, won.size(), lost.size());
                infoMovieFrag_AwardGoldenRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager
                        (context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
                infoMovieFrag_AwardGoldenRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                infoMovieFrag_AwardGoldenRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
                infoMovieFrag_AwardGoldenRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(disableRecyclerViewScroll);
                infoMovieFrag_AwardGoldenRecyclerView.setAdapter(awardGoldenAdapter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<CelebrityAwardResponse> call, Throwable t) {
        }
    });
}
```

**Show me error for this line in Adapter :**

```
if (model.get(position).getWon()) {
```

How can I fix this bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in the Activity:

```
if (won.size() > 0) {
   awardModel.addAll(won);
   awardGoldenAdapter = new AwardGoldenAdapter(context, awardModel);
} else {
   awardModel.addAll(lost);
   awardGoldenAdapter = new AwardGoldenAdapter(context, awardModel);
}
```

And also change the adapter as follow:

```
public AwardGoldenAdapter(Context context, List<Award> model) {
   this.context = context;
   this.model = model;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return this.model.size();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

add this code in your activity

```
 if (won.size() > 0) {
       awardModel.addAll(won);
       awardGoldenAdapter = new AwardGoldenAdapter(context, awardModel);
    } else {
       awardModel.addAll(lost);
       awardGoldenAdapter = new AwardGoldenAdapter(context, awardModel);
    }
```

and change your constructor like this

```
public AwardGoldenAdapter(Context context, List<Award> model) {
    this.context = context;
    this.model = model;
}
```

change `getItemCount()` method in your `AwardGoldenAdapter` like below code

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return model.size();
}
```

Comment: I should use `return total` . Please help me for this

Comment: @YoYoAnimate you should use `return model.size();` like my ans

Comment: No, she does now want to display every item in the list, so model.size is not correct

Comment: @LucaNicoletti if she use `return total;` than the error occurs

Comment: Yes, because he's creating the adapter with wrong numbers, not because he's returning what he wants.

Comment: @LucaNicoletti, yes yes my friend, I'm not show every item in the list . Can you help me? please help me my friend. please

Comment: @LucaNicoletti, can you send me true code with my above codes? I am amateur and I really need your helps . please

Comment: @NileshRathod, can you send me true code with my above codes? I am amateur and I really need your helps . please

Comment: Post a log in which you print out the values of total, won, and nominated at the end of your adapter creation, and as well before the if statement, post these 3 values

Comment: @NileshRathod actually, it's completely wrong. HE should return `.size()` and create the adapter only with wons/ not wons!

Comment: @LucaNicoletti, do you have TeamViewer? can you send me your Skype ID? please

Comment: @LucaNicoletti than he has to pass arraylist size of wons or total

Comment: @NileshRathod really? Copied my answer after I posted it?

Comment: @LucaNicoletti look i changed the constructor

Comment: you are passing two parameters in constructor and in your constructor there are four paramters

Comment: @LucaNicoletti if you think its Copied your  answer than i'll delete it

Comment: Didn't see I didn't change the Constructor signature, you fixed it! :) Sorry man!

Answer (score 2):

To remove your error just change one statement inside  `getItemCount() .`
return model.size()

Comment: I should use `return total` . Please help me for this

Comment: using that you can display only one time .

Answer (score 1):

just add notifyDataSetChanged(); to your code after delete or add